# Add space between two cards and around them (with Margin) in Blazorise

Tags: c#, html, css, margin, blazorise

How can I add some space around my cards in Blazorise?
I added some margin with classes in Column but this didn't work because only the "New Survey" gets moved down and I did it for both Columns and I also changed the Row Gutter numbers, didn't helped me out...

Heres my Image:
[image: Cards]

Here's the corresponding code:

```
        <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
            <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                    <CardTitle>
                        @localizer["SurveyPreviewTitle"]
                    </CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                    <SurveyPreviewView />
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </Column>
        <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
            <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                    <CardTitle>@localizer["StatisticTitle"]</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                    <SurveyStatsView />
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </Column>
    </Row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a wide screen so I also had to do a larger space between both cards. Because it's a high-resolution display (3440 * 1440)

To consider this I had to use larger numbers for `<Row Gutter="(64, 50)"`

I hope this helps people to get rid of the docs and answers which goes to much in details so just adjust the row gutter to "larger".

Answer (score 0):

By https://blazorise.com/docs/components/grid/

you can just use gutter.
Modify your opening Row tag to look like this for example:

```
<Row Gutter="(32, 16)">
```

another way is to use offset --

Instead of using

```
 "ColumnSize.Is6"
```

on both columns, you can use ColumnSize.Is5, and use offset of 2

first column -

```
ColumnSize.Is5
```

second column -

```
ColumnSize.Is5.Is2.WithOffset
```